# Conditional reuse of subquery

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

Can't figure this out...

Sql stored procedure has an optional argument, say an `id(int)`. For simplicity sake, say, I have to return a result set with extra `...and id=@id` check if argument is not null. If not I just return the result set.

How do I avoid writing the 'core' of the query twice? `CTE` to the rescue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try:

```
select * from myTable where id = isnull(@id, id)
```

If the `@id` is null the query compare its own id column to itself, which is always true, otherwise is the parameter used.

Comment: I see the idea. But like I said the query is complex, wondering if I need to concern myself about any performance issues of adding isnull() wherever I need the check, instead of writing two queries separately.

Comment: It will have an effect (maybe only a little) on performance but if you don't want a second query you cannot avoid that :)

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```
where .... and (@id is null or id = @id)
```

Comment: I am interested in what you think about my comment to 'aweis's answer. Thanks

Comment: That should work too. I prefer using Or as it is easier to read when I look at the code few weeks after writing it.

Comment: no, my question was regarding the performance concerns when we add new constraint

Comment: Indexes are tricky in such dynamic where clause no matter how you write the query. You will have to experiment based on most used columns and combinations.